# Formulario qml a c++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Como se puede vincular un boton en qml para que devuelva unos parametros en c++

Ejemplo:

```
//QML

Item {
    Button {
        onClick: {
            mensaje();
        }
    }
}

//C++

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl ...
    engine.load(url);
    
    QString mensaje = mensaje();


    return app.exec();
}
```

Lo que quiero que haga es que al presionar en qml el boton el codigo en c++ pueda ejecutarse y leerse para poder ejecutar mas código

Answer (score 0):

Aunque hay varias maneras de conectar e integrar C++ y QML, un caso sencillo podría hacerse mediante señales. Un ejemplo básico sería este:

La conexión entre ambos (QML y C++) se haría en la función `main`:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "myclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

     QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
     engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
     QObject *item = engine.rootObjects().first();

     MyClass myClass;
     QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)),
                      &myClass, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));

     return app.exec();
}
```

La señal se emitiría en QML al pulsar cierto `Button`:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    signal qmlSignal(string msg)

    Button {
        id: add
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        text: qsTr("add")
        onClicked: qmlSignal(text)
    }
}
```

Y ya el slot puede definirse e implementarse en C++:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void cppSlot(const QString &msg) {
        qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot with message:" << msg;
    }
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```